# Bokeh server application - ImportError

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, bokeh

I am trying to import functions from module1.py and module2.py in main.py as shown below.

```
# my imports in main.py

from project_dir.bokeh_apps.scripts.module1 import func1
from project_dir.bokeh_apps.scripts.module2 import func2
```

below is my example of how my folder structure looks like

```
project/
    project_dir/
        bokeh_apps/
            scripts/
                module1.py
                module2.py
                __init__.py
            main.py
            __init__.py
        dir_1/
        dir_2/
        __init__.py
    dev.ini
    prod.ini
```

I am getting below error

```
Error running application handler <bokeh.application.handlers.directory.DirectoryHandler object at 0x7fbf647e4208>: No module named 'project_dir.bokeh_apps.scripts'
File "main.py", line 13, in <module>:
from project_dir.bokeh_apps.scripts.module1 import func1 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/.conda/envs/test_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bokeh/application/handlers/code_runner.py", line 81, in run
     exec(self._code, module.__dict__)
  File "/var/www/projects/project/project_dir/bokeh_apps/main.py", line 13, in <module>
     from project_dir.bokeh_apps.scripts.module1 import func1
ImportError: No module named 'project_dir.bokeh_apps.scripts'
```

I am running bokeh server as below

```
bokeh serve bokeh_apps/
```

**Environment**
*(My environment is same on both dev and staging)*

```
Python 3.5
Pyramid 1.5.7
bokeh 0.12.6
tornado 4.5.1
```

**Note:** 
I tested everything on my dev instance, it works fine and no issues. When I am testing this on my staging instance I am getting these errors.

Please correct me if I am doing anything wrong! Any help on this issue will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: AFAIK you would need an `__init__.py` in `scripts` for this to work (I'm not sure why it would ever work without it)

Comment: @bigreddot Sorry, I forgot to mention above. But there is already `__init__.py` file inside `scripts` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was helpful for me in order to organize imports. You will need to adapt it to your needs:

### [Create Custom Python Package](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/minimal.html)

The best way to organize imports in a python app is to create a new package and install it. The package will coincide with the main container folder name. Folders structure:

```
funniest/
    funniest/
        __init__.py
    setup.py
```

The content of `__init__.py`

```
def joke():
    return (u'Wenn ist das Nunst\u00fcck git und Slotermeyer? Ja! ... '
            u'Beiherhund das Oder die Flipperwaldt gersput.')
```

In this main folder create a `setup.py` file with this content

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='funniest',
      version='0.1',
      description='The funniest joke in the world',
      url='http://github.com/storborg/funniest',
      author='Flying Circus',
      author_email='flyingcircus@example.com',
      license='MIT',
      packages=['funniest'],
      zip_safe=False)
```

Install the package

```
pip install .               # install the package completely
pip install -e .            # only symbolic link
```

So now this should work

```
>>> import funniest         # the __init__.py file of this module is executed
>>> print funniest.joke()
```